# Hide Drawer navigator hamburger icon on certain screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v6

NOTE: Do guide me if there is something missing.
I have a Drawer Navigator which contains Drawer Screens that are Stack Screens like:

```
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator
          screenOptions={({ }) => ({
            // headerShown: false,
            // title:"",
            headerTransparent: true,
            headerTitle: "",
          })}>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Groups" component={GroupsScreen} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Rides" component={RidesScreen} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
```

The problem is that the Drawer Navigator's header hamburger shows up on HomeScreen and each and every helper screen etc. inside it. I want to show on the first screen which is "HomeHelper" but want to hide on other screens to which it navigates such as "**ListOfRides**" screen.

HomeScreen:

```js
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={() => ({
        headerTitle: "",
        headerTransparent: true,
        //headerShown:false
      })}>
      {rideBooked == true ? (
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen} 
        options={{
          headerRight: () => (
            <Button
              onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
            >Cancel</Button>
          ),
        }}/>

      ) : (
        <>
        {/* headertransparent for these */}
          <Stack.Screen name="HomeHelper" component={HomeHelperScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="ListOfRides" component={ListOfRidesScreen} />
        </>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
screenOptions={{
      header:()=> `ENTER YOUR VIEW HERE`,
      headerShown: true,
      tabBarShowLabel: true,
      animation: 'fade',
    }}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?